# wait_event and lock interaction

Tags: linux-kernel, locking

I'm new to linux kernel development and wonder how `wait_event/wait_event_interruptible` interacts with other locking primitives in the kernel. I'm used to C++ `std::condition_variable::wait` and want to achieve something similar in the kernel.

I have a queue of receive buffers which are filled using DMA transfers. The list is protected using a spin lock. Finished buffers are added by the DMA finished soft IRQ. I created a character device which allows reading of the finished buffers. So far this works as expected but I want to support blocking reads.

I've read about `wait_event` which seems like what I want, but I'm really confused how `wait_event` does not take any lock/mutex parameter. How is evaluating the condition without holding a lock safe? I suppose I can add the necessary locking to my condition, but then I need to lock again once `wait_event` returns to extract the data. Is this already a case for `prepare_to_wait/schedule/finish_wait`?

Answer (score 0):

Without digging to much into the source first I will say you should be using the wait_event library and you do not need mutex's or other such things the kernel is taking care of them. Personally I only have experience with *wait_event_interruptible* and *wake_up_interruptible* but I suspect they all are similar.

Now onto the source which I am pulling from https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/wait.h#L302

```
#define ___wait_event(wq_head, condition, state, exclusive, ret, cmd)       \
({                                      \
    __label__ __out;                            \
    struct wait_queue_entry __wq_entry;                 \
    long __ret = ret;   /* explicit shadow */               \
                                        \
    init_wait_entry(&__wq_entry, exclusive ? WQ_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE : 0);    \
    for (;;) {                              \
        long __int = prepare_to_wait_event(&wq_head, &__wq_entry, state);\
                                        \
        if (condition)                          \
            break;                          \
                                        \
        if (___wait_is_interruptible(state) && __int) {         \
            __ret = __int;                      \
            goto __out;                     \
        }                               \
                                        \
        cmd;                                \
    }                                   \
    finish_wait(&wq_head, &__wq_entry);                 \
__out:  __ret;                                  \
})

long prepare_to_wait_event(struct wait_queue_head *wq_head, struct wait_queue_entry *wq_entry, int state)
{
    unsigned long flags;
    long ret = 0;

    spin_lock_irqsave(&wq_head->lock, flags);
....
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&wq_head->lock, flags);

    return ret;
}
```

As can be seen the wait library is using spin_locks already which are similar to mutex's (although slightly different). The nice thing about using the wait library is that a lot of safety checks to keep the kernel happy and going are automatically performed for you but it still performs the necessary block on your data. If you need more of an example on using the wait_event_* and it's assosciated wake_up_* calls let me know and I can fetch one.

Comment: I'm talking about the lock which is required to access my list. Since the list gets filled from a soft IRQ and read from user context I need some kind of synchronization between them. And this is a different lock than the wait_event internal one.